# Focus restoration on navigation popBackStack and focus restoration using state Modifiers

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-tv

In the [JetStream](https://github.com/android/tv-samples/blob/main/JetStreamCompose/jetstream/src/main/java/com/google/jetstream/presentation/utils/ModifierUtils.kt#L134C5-L134C40) tv app sample, it has a `createInitialFocusRestorerModifiers()` function which acts as the focus restorers of a TvLazyRow/Column for its children.

As said from the function's KDoc:

> Returns a set of modifiers [FocusRequesterModifiers] which can be used
> for restoring focus and specifying the initially focused item.

Its usage:

```
  LazyRow(modifier.then(modifiers.parentModifier) {
   item1(modifier.then(modifiers.childModifier) {...}
   item2 {...}
   item3 {...}
   ...
  }
```

[image: NestedLazyList composables]
The proper behavior should be the following image. Pressing DPad down should focus to the first item, and up should bring to the last saved state focus child.

Though, the problem here is it does not restore focus on navigation [`popBackStack()`] so I tried to integrate the said function with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76618761/19371763).

Current code:

```
        // var anItemHasBeenFocused: Boolean = false
        // var lastFocusedItem: Pair<Int, Int> = ...

        TvLazyRow(
            modifier = focusRestorerModifiers.parentModifier,
            pivotOffsets = PivotOffsets(parentFraction = 0F)
        ) {
            itemsIndexed(items = items) { columnIndex, item ->
                val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
                
                RowItem(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .focusRequester(focusRequester)
                        .ifElse(
                            condition = columnIndex == 0,
                            ifTrueModifier = focusRestorerModifiers.childModifier
                        )
                        .onPlaced {
                            val shouldFocusThisItem = lastFocusedItem.first == rowIndex
                                && lastFocusedItem.second == columnIndex
                                && !anItemHasBeenFocused

                            if (shouldFocusThisItem) {
                                // The stacktrace points here.
                                focusRequester.requestFocus()
                            }
                        }
                        .onFocusChange {
                            if(it.isFocused) {
                                onFocusedChange(item, columnIndex)
                            }
                        }
                        .focusProperties {
                            if (rowIndex == 0) {
                                up = FocusRequester.Cancel
                            } else if (isLastIndex) {
                                down = FocusRequester.Cancel
                            }
                        },
                    item = item,
                    isLastIndex = columnIndex == items.lastIndex,
                    onClick = onNavigateToSecondScreen
                )

        }
```

The code worked fine on the first item only, I was able to go back without any errors from the second screen after navigating thru the first item.

When I tried to scroll to the end item of the list - making the first item hidden from the current view - and tried to go to my second screen and immediately pop back from it, the app constantly throws:

```
   FocusRequester is not initialized. Here are some possible fixes:
   1. Remember the FocusRequester: val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
   2. Did you forget to add a Modifier.focusRequester() ?
   3. Are you attempting to request focus during composition? Focus requests should be made in
   response to some event. Eg Modifier.clickable { focusRequester.requestFocus() }
```

Question: How do I achieve this kind of focus behavior? Being able to combine both initial state focus restorers and navigation state focus restoring?

Comment: When you scroll to the end of the list and change the screen, the item that gained focus at the end would be last item in the list. So, when you come back to this screen, the last item's focus requester should be the one to request focus and not the first item. I tried to reproduce this crash with the provided code but I failed to do so. Would it be possible for you to create a small github repo containing minimum amount of code to reproduce this issue?

Comment: @vighnesh153 hi! thanks for the initiative! here is the repo: https://github.com/rhenwinch/ComposeTvFocusTest

Comment: I am able to reproduce the error. The `focusRequester.restoreFocusedChild`  doesn't seem to be returning the previouslyFocusedChild when used with NavHost and because of that, it is falling back to request focus to the first item of the row (which is not in view) and causes the crash.

Comment: @vighnesh153 I think I fixed it. remember-ing the firstVisibleItemIndex on the list state after coming back from a navigation could be the trick. Since `i == 0` is not visible on the screen, we could replace it with the first visible index `i == firstVisibleItemIndex`. This way the parentModifier will not throw an error if its looking for its childModifier.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### 1. Update to Latest builds/versions to avoid dealing with issues which might have already been fixed

Since the build id in your repository is severely out of date, I would first recommend that you

- Either switch to either the latest alpha version (`1.0.0-alpha08` as of today)
- If you want to continue using snapshot versions, you can update the build id in the `settings.gradle.kts`. Checkout [latest working androidx snapshot builds](https://androidx.dev/snapshots/builds) for finding the latest build ids.

```kotlin
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { 
            val buildId = "10639124"
            url = URI.create(
                "https://androidx.dev/snapshots/builds/$buildId/artifacts/repository"
            ) 
        }
    }
}
```

### 2. Coming to your question (WORKAROUND)

> Note: Since the focus restoration API is slightly new and experimental, the usage is constantly evolving. I will try to keep this answer update-to-date when a better usage comes up. There is also a bug in focus restoration which prevents remembering focus across nested lazy containers. Once it gets resolved, we won't have to do the following tedious stuff to transfer focus to the last focused item.

Instead of passing down lastFocusedItem state to all the child components, we can make use of CompositionLocal to store the stuff. Following are some sample utility composition locals that we will make use of, in the demo below.

```kotlin
private val LocalLastFocusedItemPerDestination = compositionLocalOf<MutableMap<String, String>?> { null }
private val LocalFocusTransferredOnLaunch = compositionLocalOf<MutableState<Boolean>?> { null }
private val LocalNavHostController = compositionLocalOf<NavHostController?> { null }

@Composable
fun LocalLastFocusedItemPerDestinationProvider(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    CompositionLocalProvider(LocalLastFocusedItemPerDestination provides remember { mutableMapOf() }, content = content)
}

@Composable
fun LocalFocusTransferredOnLaunchProvider(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    CompositionLocalProvider(LocalFocusTransferredOnLaunch provides remember { mutableStateOf(false) }, content = content)
}

@Composable
fun LocalNavHostControllerProvider(navHostController: NavHostController, content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    CompositionLocalProvider(LocalNavHostController provides navHostController, content = content)
}

@Composable
fun useLocalLastFocusedItemPerDestination(): MutableMap<String, String> {
    return LocalLastFocusedItemPerDestination.current ?: throw RuntimeException("Please wrap your app with LocalLastFocusedItemPerDestinationProvider")
}

@Composable
fun useLocalFocusTransferredOnLaunch(): MutableState<Boolean> {
    return LocalFocusTransferredOnLaunch.current ?: throw RuntimeException("Please wrap your app with LocalLastFocusedItemPerDestinationProvider")
}

@Composable
fun useLocalNavHostController(): NavHostController {
    return LocalNavHostController.current ?: throw RuntimeException("Please wrap your app with LocalNavHostControllerProvider")
}
```

With the above utilities in place, we can now create a modifier which would focus the item when the Nav Destination is launched. In this modifier, we will check if this was the last focused item before the Nav destination was changed, and if yes, we will request focus onto this item.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Modifier.focusOnMount(itemKey: String): Modifier {
    val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
    val isInitialFocusTransferred = useLocalFocusTransferredOnLaunch()
    val lastFocusedItemPerDestination = useLocalLastFocusedItemPerDestination()
    val navHostController = useLocalNavHostController()
    val currentDestination = remember(navHostController) { navHostController.currentDestination?.route }

    return this
        .focusRequester(focusRequester)
        .onGloballyPositioned {
            val lastFocusedKey = lastFocusedItemPerDestination[currentDestination]
            if (!isInitialFocusTransferred.value && lastFocusedKey == itemKey) {
                focusRequester.requestFocus()
                isInitialFocusTransferred.value = true
            }
        }
        .onFocusChanged {
            if (it.isFocused) {
                lastFocusedItemPerDestination[currentDestination ?: ""] = itemKey
                isInitialFocusTransferred.value = true
            }
        }
}
```

Usage of this modifier is pretty straight forward. Wrap the screens with the utility providers we created above and assign the `focusOnMount` modifier to all the focusable items (like buttons, cards, tabs, etc.) on your page.

> Notice that `LocalFocusTransferredOnLaunchProvider` is provided separately at each screen level.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun App() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    LocalNavHostControllerProvider(navController) {
        LocalLastFocusedItemPerDestinationProvider {
            NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "home") {
                composable("home") {
                    LocalFocusTransferredOnLaunchProvider {
                        HomePage()
                    }
                }
                composable("movie") {
                    LocalFocusTransferredOnLaunchProvider {
                        Button(
                            modifier = Modifier.focusOnMount("home button"),
                            onClick = { navController.popBackStack() }
                        ) {
                            Text("Home")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun HomePage() {
    TvLazyColumn {
        items(15) { row ->
            val navController = useLocalNavHostController()
        
            Column {
                Text(text = "Row $row")
        
                val focusRestorerModifiers = createInitialFocusRestorerModifiers()
        
                TvLazyRow(modifier = focusRestorerModifiers.parentModifier) {
                    items(15) { column ->
                        val key = "row=$row, column=$column"
                        key(key) {
                            Card(
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .ifElse(
                                        condition = column == 0,
                                        ifTrueModifier = focusRestorerModifiers.childModifier
                                    )
                                    .focusOnMount(key),
                                onClick = { navController?.navigate("movie") }
                            ) {}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Notice the usage of key and `key` composable. When using focus restoration, wrapping your focusable item in a `key` composable is important.

You might also observe that when the app first launches, nothing is focused. To fix this, you can update the `LocalLastFocusedItemPerDestinationProvider` to initialise with the keys of items that should get focus initially.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun LocalLastFocusedItemPerDestinationProvider(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalLastFocusedItemPerDestination provides remember {
            mutableMapOf(
                "home" to "row=0, column=0",
                "movie" to "home button"
            )
        },
        content = content
    )
}
```

[image]

Comment: Very well put! Ive never used CompositionLocalProviders before. Those utils provided better code readeability!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation here but I'm still facing an issue within the focus restorer.
implementing your workaround solution is working only when the item I need to restore the focus is within the LazyColmn restore scope.
in my case, when scrolling more than 5 rows and back to the start point row the focus can't be restored with parentFocusRequester.restoreFocusedChild()
so instead of getting the focused item before, it tries to get the childFocusRequester - and if the item is in the bounds of the screen then it automatically scroll to it, but if not it will crash

Comment: I am not sure what error is causing the app to crash for you. If it is "Focus requester is not initialized", then there is an open issue for it here: [b/330696779](https://issuetracker.google.com/330696779)